# HTML - Inputs not going below each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 2 input boxes that are stacked one below the other. However even with `display:block`, they continue to show side by side.

```css
#form-wrapper
{
 height:100%;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="form-wrapper">
     <form id="withdraw-form">
         <input class="input"/>
         <input class="input"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Yet, this is what I get:
[image: img]

Comment: inputs are inline elements .. http://jsfiddle.net/wbrom5q9/

Comment: Why should they? `<input />` elements are inline. You're setting the form to `display: block` not the inputs. Add `#form-wrapper input { display: block; }`...

Comment: You know what! - add a `<br>` in between, that is what it's designed for.

Comment: @sdcr That's definitely not what the [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) element should be used for. That's very poor semantics.

Comment: @Oka really? it depends on if this is a html or css question. Imagine what if you take off the css in the browser, and you have 100 input fields.

Comment: @sdcr https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br "The HTML <br> Element (or HTML Line Break Element) produces a line break in **text**"

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for pointing that out, and I agree with it. It's very obvious most of the people (including you and me) would use the css way to fix it. But I believe lots of back-end guys would prefer the <br> tag. I'm just suggesting, so there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `display: block`isn't hitting the input element

```
#form-wrapper
{
    height:100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}

#form-wrapper input{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle.net/wbrom5q9](http://jsfiddle.net/wbrom5q9)

```
#form-wrapper
{
    height:100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
#form-wrapper input {
display:block;
}
```